# Gráfico de horas no Highcharts?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Estou tentando fazer um gráfico parecido com este e não estou conseguindo. Alguém poderia me ajudar?[image: Dados necessários para o gráfico]

Lembrando que a tabela pode ser ignorada, eu só queria o gráfico mesmo.

Comment: Como assim, qual a sua dificuldade? Fazer o gráfico funcionar ou importar os valores do banco?

Comment: Minha dificuldade é fazer o gráfico entender valores de horas. Por exemplo
01:00:00, 00:30:00, 04:23:00 ... e meu gráfico respeitar esses valores, entendeu?

Comment: Queria fazer exatamente o gráfico da imagem, porém o da imagem foi feito no excel, eu gostaria de fazer no highchart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer um gráfico no `Highchart` precisamos seguir alguns passos:

Primeiro, entre no site https://www.highcharts.com/download e faça o download do **highcharts 6.1.1**. Feito isso, copie a pasta **code** e **examples** de dentro da pasta do **highcharts** para dentro da pasta do sistema que você está desenvolvendo.

Dentro da pasta **examples** vão ter várias outras pastas com os arquivos de cada tipo de gráfico. Para o seu gráfico, vamos usar o **combo-dual-axes**.

Agora você já tem um gráfico, mas ele não pega os valores da sua tabela, é um gráfico com valores pré programados, então, vamos colocar os valores da sua tabela.

A primeira coisa que vamos fazer é copiar o conteúdo da página do seu gráfico escolhido e colar em uma nova página que você vai salvar como um arquivo **php**. Isso porque vamos precisar do **php** pra pegar os valores da sua tabela no banco de dados e colocar dentro do gráfico.

Agora que você tem uma página **php** com o gráfico dentro, vamos fazer os `selects` pra pegar os valores de cada coluna, fazer uma array pra cada e colocar as arrays que criamos dentro das arrays do highcharts:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Seu gráfico</title>

        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="code/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="code/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>



<div class="col-sm-6 sm-margin-b-2">
  <div class="">
    <div class="" data-height="height"> 
      <div class="service-info"> 
        <?php

         $lnk = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
         mysqli_select_db($lnk,'SeuBanco') or die(mysql_error());


          $Yr16 = mysqli_query($lnk, "Select JAN, FEV, MAR, ABR, MAI, JUN, JUL, AGO, SET, OUT, NOV, DEZ from Yr16 where MMTR = 'Yr16' ");
          $BP17 = mysqli_query($lnk, "Select JAN, FEV, MAR, ABR, MAI, JUN, JUL, AGO, SET, OUT, NOV, DEZ from B917 where MMTR = 'B917' ");
          $Yr17 = mysqli_query($lnk, "Select JAN, FEV, MAR, ABR, MAI, JUN, JUL, AGO, SET, OUT, NOV, DEZ from Yr17 where MMTR = 'Yr17' ");


          $resultYr16 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Yr16);

          $resultBP17 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($BP17);

          $resultYr17 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Yr17);

          $ListaYr16 = $resultYr16; 
          $ListaBP17 = $resultBP17; 
          $ListaYr16 = $resultYr17; 
          $ListaYr16Total = array();
          $ListaBP17Total = array();
          $ListaYr17Total = array();

          foreach ($ListaYr16 as $i => $value) {
            array_push($ListaYr16Total, $value);
          }

          foreach ($ListaBP17 as $i => $value) {
            array_push($ListaBP17Total, $value);
          }

          foreach ($ListaYr17 as $i => $value) {
            array_push($ListaYr17Total, $value);
          }


          $html1 = "
            <div id='container-tt-1' style='min-width: 210px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto'></div>

              <script type='text/javascript'>
                Highcharts.chart('container-tt-1', {
                  chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                  },
                  title: {
                    text: 'Gráfico de horas'
                  },
                  xAxis: {
                    categories: [
                      'Jan',
                      'Feb',
                      'Mar',
                      'Apr',
                      'May',
                      'Jun',
                      'Jul',
                      'Aug',
                      'Sep',
                      'Oct',
                      'Nov',
                      'Dec'
                    ],
                    crosshair: true
                  },
                  yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {                             
                    }
                  },
                  tooltip: {

                    shared: true,
                    useHTML: true
                  },
                  plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                      pointPadding: 0.2,
                      borderWidth: 0
                    }
                  },
                  series: [{
                    name: 'Yr16',
                    data: [" . join(", ", $ListaYr16Total) . "]

                  }, {
                    name: 'Yr17',
                    data: [" . join(", ", $ListaYr17Total) . "]

                  } , {
                    name: 'BP17',
                    data: [" .  join(", ", $ListaBP17Total) . "]

                  }]
                  });
              </script>";

            echo $html1;

              ?>                           
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Eu inventei o nome das colunas de acordo com o que estava na imagem, mas caso seja diferente é só alterar.

É aconselhável que esse arquivo esteja na pasta principal do seu sistema, então, você pode até excluir a pasta exemples depois disso se você quiser.

Agora você já deve ter o gráfico puxando as informações do seu banco de dados.

Espero ter ajudado.